# How to free up "Other" in Storage Management

Tags: storage

[image: Storage management windows]

Storage management show me "Other" is 127.51 GB
but I can't do anything even see any information.

What is inside? And how to get rid of it?

Comment: This has been closed, but none of the linked questions answer the problem.